# How to build Jenkins WAR from Source

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to build Jenkins WAR file from GitHub source https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins.

When I try to build using `mvn clean install` I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from repo.jenkins-ci.org: https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/jenkins/1.52/jenkins-1.52.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-parent:${revision}${changelist}: Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci:jenkins:pom:1.52 from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org (https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 28, column 11
```

I am using Windows 10, Oracle JDK jdk1.8.0_131 and apache-maven-3.6.1.

Looking at the error message I feel I need to generate and install some certificates, but I don't exactly know how. Any guidelines?

Comment: The [contributor documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#building-and-debugging) suggests `mvn clean package -pl war -am -DskipTests -Dfindbugs.skip`. Does that work for you? (Specifically, does the `package` goal work better than `install`?)

Comment: the problem related to this: `...//repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification` cause it looks you are using either JDK6 etc. or not correctly configured your JDK...

Comment: Thanks Daniel Pryden for your reply, the command you have provided does not resolve the issue, it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Thanks Khmarbaise for your reply, i'm using JDK 1.8.0.131, will try to upgrade it to latest version of 1.8 and then will try again to make build and share the results.